# Why don't careers site applicants have links to their careers CV when applying?

Tags: feature-request, support, jobs

I'm looking at a handfull of applications on the careers site, but I can't look at any of their CVs. There's no link to get to something such as [my public CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/briang) from their applications.

What I have from an applicant:

```
From:
John Fakey Smith
JohnFakeySmith@example.com
Cyrodiil

Hello, my name is John, but on the internet I'm known as 
"U17im4t3 D357rt0c0n 9000". I'm a rock star hot shot coder. 
I pwn bytes, brah.

Love,
UD9k

> Resume.pdf
```

There's no real way to access his CV, or lurk him on Stack Overflow, which is really disapointing from the perspective of both the applicant (I didn't know this was the case, I should start linking in my CV I suppose), and an employer (I wanted to lurk them and see if they actually ask the right questions or see code samples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely the applicant is an anonymous candidate and they do not have an account on the Careers site.  When this is the case, the only thing we have to give you is the resume they give us.  When the candidate does have an account on Careers, you get a link in the email pointing you directly to a page to view their profile.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea this was the case. All my applicants appear to be anonymous in that case.